# No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm doing a project sample by using ASP.Net Core RC2 with `Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core` and SQLite.

I've followed this tutorial: 
https://damienbod.com/2015/08/30/asp-net-5-with-sqlite-and-entity-framework-7/

But, when I run this command :

```
dotnet ef migrations add FirstMigration
```

I got this error :

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

Here is my `project.json` configuration:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This announcement shows how your project.json should look like in RC2 if you are using tools: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/172

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Entity Framework Core 1.0**

You should just need to update the `tools` section of your project.json file to include this:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

This should make the `dotnet ef` commands available.

**Important**

I should also note here that the `dotnet ef` commands will only be available when running them from the same directory which contains the project.json file.

**Entity Framework Core 1.1**
If you are having this problem again after upgrading to Entity Framework Core 1.1, be sure to replace the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` dependency with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` version `1.1.0-preview4`. There is no need to keep the `imports` section, either. For more information on this, see the "Upgrading to 1.1" heading under the [Entity Framework Core 1.1 release announcement blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/).

Comment: Not being in the folder with `project.json` was my problem, thanks!

Comment: It does not work for me. I keep getting the same error.

Comment: @NikolaSchou: In the tools section, try without the structure, i.e. just adding the version. E.g.:
`  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },`

Comment: @ArveHansen The problem turned out to be, that it was a class library. The tools started working after adding  "buildOptions": { "emitEntryPoint": true  } to project.json and adding an Main-class to the project.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390420/cannot-run-dotnet-ef-on-ef6-after-upgrading-to-net-core-1-0-project-files/39390729?noredirect=1#comment66108686_39390729

Comment: Comment running from same directory as project.json was helpful.

Comment: @NikolaSchou You also have to reopen cmd.

Comment: Please open the "src" folder, I had the same problem.

Comment: @Adrian, thank you too. After a long time I come back to .net core. I faced with the old problem as the time I asked this question. So funny

Comment: Whether you're using a csproj file or project.json, you have to be in that folder.

Answer (score 56):

**Entity Framework Core 1.1**

Adding in on this if you're using VS2017 with the new .csproj projects without a project.json file

you need to edit the .csproj file (right click it in solution explorer and click edit whatever.csproj) and then paste this in

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet">
      <Version>1.0.0-*</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

courtesy of : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7358#issuecomment-278379967

Comment: it works but, need to know the correct version. As i am new it was also very difficult for me to figure out the correct version. So anyone following the answer know your Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet version and put in version tag. i.e <Version>2.0.3</Version>

Comment: This really saves my day. Thx! I updated `VS2017` and it automatically updated `dotnet core CLI` to `2.0` version which is not compatible with `dotnet core 1.0`. But it seems it's the time that I should update my project `.net core 1.0` to `2.0`.

Answer (score 40):

Specific to VS2017 15.3 or greater and ASP.NET CORE 2.0 or later...

Install nuget for db provider via command line or nuget package manager.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Add following section to .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" 
    Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Install design time tools via commandline or nuget manager in VS2017.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

This enables dotnet ef * at the command line in the project directory.

Enables dotnet ef * commands at the command line in the project directory,

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
dotnet ef database update Initial
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
```

Comment: Great answer, I was looking everything and the section on adding to the 'ItemGroup' was what was really blocking for me on .NET Core 2 Web API using EF Core 2.

Comment: Same here. The `DotNetCliToolReference ` with Tools.DotNet was the key in my case

Comment: This fixed my problem, Same issue with NET Core 2 Web API using EF Core 2

Answer (score 32):

This is a common issue when switching from .NET Core 1.0 to .NET Core 1.1+ or 2.x.

To fix that, you need to:

- Get the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** and **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet** package libraries using NuGet.
- Manually add a reference to this package within your `project.json` (for .NET Core 1.0) or `<projectName>.csproj` (for .NET Core 1.1+ & 2.x) project configuration file.

More specifically, for .NET Core 1.0 projects, add this:

```
"tools": {
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0"
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0"
 }
```

For .NET Core 1.1+ and .NET Core 2.x projects, add this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference 
      Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" 
      Version="2.0.0" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference 
      Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" 
      Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you already have a `tools` json key or an `<ItemGroup>` element with one or more existing `DotNetCliToolReference` elements, just add the new ones to the existing group.

**IMPORTANT**: other than performing the above steps, you have to launch the `dotnet ef` command within the project root folder (the one containing the project file), otherwise it won't work.

For additional info and an extensive explanation of the issue you can read more on [my blog post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef-error-in-visual-studio-2017-and-net-core-2-vs2017-entity-framework/).

Comment: Thanks mate you save the day :)

Comment: How do you launch the dotnet ef command within the project root folder?

Comment: @IanWarburton by having `C:\Program Files\dotnet` in the PATH environment variable OR by using the full path, i.e.  `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe`

Comment: Worked for me in .NET Core 2.0. The accepted solution didn't work for me. IMPORTANT section did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I think I have found the **Accurate solution** for the problem - **dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"**..

I am using dot net core 2.0 in VS 2017 versio 15.5.3

> ***Cause of this error***

This error is caused because the **Nuget** is **not able to find** the **solution file** on the location.

> ***Solution:- Move to the directory where you have the 'Startup.cs' class***

1. I Moved to the **root** by adding the below **command** on your **Package Manager Console**.

   cd .\School1

Here 'School1' was my **root directory** of the project, and it contains my 'Startup.cs' class, it will be different in your case.

2. Then run the command `dotnet ef` on **Package Manager Console** which will now run successfully.

> ***Example With Pictures for Clear Understanding***

1. I got error Error when running `dotnet ef`.
   [image]
2. I corrected the error by moving to the root folder with the command `cd .\School1`

Hope it helps my fellow Dot Net Developers.

[image]

Comment: yes, this helped me to fix similar type of issue I was facing.Thanks.

Comment: it helps me in some extent. For my case to solve the problem i also follow @Michael Freidgeim 's answer

Answer (score 12):

I had to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.**DotNet** to work.  The tools section of your project.json file will look like this:

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools":"1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
},
```

Comment: There is not "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet"

Comment: There is ... in Browse through Manage NuGet Packages GUI the search term .Tools.DotNet will bring it up.  Latest pre-release is 1.1.0-preview4-final.

Answer (score 4):

If you met this problem and run the asp.net core with CLI tool, you may solve it by adding 

`<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />`

into xx.csproj file, and

`dotnet restore`
. 
Then you can use dotnet ef command.

Comment: I actually ran into the same issue.  I was using 2.0.2 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet, and update the proj file, reloaded the project, and then retested and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my case `dotnet ef` wasn't available and not showing in the list when `dotnet -h` is run.

I've installed globally dotnet-ef with following command and I'm now able to use it. But still not in the list.

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening a separate console window in VS Package Manager Console type and run the following commands:

> Add migration
>
> `Add-Migration <migration name>`
>
> Remove last migration
>
> `Remove-Migration`
>
> Before a migration has been applied (or, to apply migration):
>
> `Update-Database`
>
> When migration has been applied:
>
> `Update-Database -Migration <previous migration> -Context <db context name>`

HTH

**EDIT**: You may also need the following class in your MVC core project:

```
public class DbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<NotesContext>
{
    public YourDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection", optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(YourDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
        return new YourDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under visual studio 2017 i needed to run these commands from package manager console

```
install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Model -Context "MyApp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a separate class library project. After trying and failing all of above in package manager console. I used command prompt, and it worked! Weird.
However, credit goes to [this article](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef/).
And if you are using separate class library project, [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt742867) is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In tools section add below code,

```
 "tools": {

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {

      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

This format of code solved my error.

Answer (score 0):

By default when adding a NuGet Pkg it will be added as a PackageReference, this is wrong, so edit it manually

1- Edit .csproj file

2- change from "PackageReference":

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3"/>
</ItemGroup>
to:
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.1"/>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3"/>
</ItemGroup>
```