# dnvm is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: asp.net-core, dnvm

I just installed rc2 of aspnet core. I have a project setup and I'd like to create a database by adding some migrations. However when I attempted to open the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 and run dnvm it says the command isn't recognized. Also running "dotnet ef" throws a similar error. Any ideas?

Comment: RC2 doesn't use DNVM.  If you're able to run `dotnet` but not `dotnet ef`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276882/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef/37280326#37280326)

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by removing "C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm" manually.

Comment: This should be a comment.