# Cannot run 'dotnet ef' on EF6 after upgrading to .NET Core 1.0 project files

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

After upgrading all project.json files to the new format for .NET core I cannot run 'dotnet ef' for Entity Framework 6 migrations. Can anybody see what is wrong with the project.json below?

Before my project.json looked like this:

```
{
   "frameworks": {
     "dnx46": {
       "dependencies": {
       }
     }
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
     "EntityFramework.DynamicFilters": "1.4.8-*",
     "Migrator.EF6": "1.1.0",
     ....
   },
   "commands": {
     "ef": "Migrator.EF6"
   }
 }
```

Now it looks like this:

```
    {
      ...
      "frameworks": {
        "net46": {
          "dependencies": {
          }
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0",
        "EntityFramework.DynamicFilters": "1.4.8-*",
        "Migrator.EF6": "1.2.0",
        "Migrator.EF6.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.3",
          "target": "package",
          "type": "build"
        },
        ...
      },
      "tools": {
        "Migrator.EF6.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.3",
          "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
        }
      }
    }
```

This is the error message I currently have when I run 'dotnet ef':

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.CommandUnknownException: No executable
>   found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add this in your `project.json` file.

```
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true
}
```

Also, if you don't have a Main class add an empty Main class like this:

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion! After adding this it complained that no main-program was present. So after adding an empty Main class it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please put your issue as a new question @ZainAlabdinTawfiq Then you'll have a better feedback.

Comment: sorry, please ignore, I will delete