# "No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef""

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to learn the basics of ASP.NET Core using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model):

1. I have created a ASP.NET Core web application
2. I have upgraded it using instruction from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/)

Now, I am trying to setup the database migration using `dotnet ef migrations add Initial` from command prompt within project's folder (where project.json is located):

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

I have changed project.json, so that dotnet-ef works:

```
"tools": {
...
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",                
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

Now, the generation fails with the following error:

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version
>   '1.0.0-rc2-3002702' was not found.
>     - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>         C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
>     - The following versions are installed:
>         1.0.0
>         1.0.1
>         1.1.0
>     - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702'

Ok, it makes sense, because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.0.0-preview1-final relies on the old version mentioned in the error, as found in the project.lock.json file.

I don't want to downgrade, so I put the latest version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools I could find:

```
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
},
```

Doing this will lead to the same error:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

How can I make it work in version 1.1?

Other context information that might be useful:

OS: Windows 7 x64
VS: 2015 Community Edition
Other parts from project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.1": {
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
},

"runtimes": {
"win7-x64": {}
},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#37276882](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765523/1233379): in short words, you need to manually edit your project configuration file and add a reference to the Tools / Tools.DotNet packages (as VS2015/VS2017 won't do that automatically). For further info, [read here](http://www.ryadel.com/en/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef-error-in-visual-studio-2017-and-net-core-2-vs2017-entity-framework/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276882/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE [30/3/2017]**

The new package is

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

<strike>Try adding</strike>

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4"
  }
```

Additionally here is a tutorial on setting up .Net Core 1.1.0 with EF Core 1.1.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite

Comment: It worked. I also lacked `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": { "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final"`

Answer (score 1):

`Grierson`'s answer is ok, but for future reference I will include the whole process until I made it work:

1) Tools.DotNet already suggested in the accepted answer

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4"
  }
```

Ran the same command and received:

> Cannot execute this command because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed. Install the version of that package that matches the installed version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and try again.

2) Added

```
//EF Core
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "type": "build"
}
```

3) Now, the error is:

> No parameterless constructor was found on 'ApplicationDbContext'.
>   Either add a parameterless constructor to 'Application DbContext' or
>   add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in
>   the same assembly as 'ApplicationDbC ontext'.

I have chosen to implement the interface. One possible way:

```
public ApplicationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
    builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Movies;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
}
```

The same error occurs when running `dotnet ef migrations add Initial`

4) I have added a default constructor for `ApplicationDbContext` class

Now I can add the migration.

Answer (score 0):

EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0-preview4-final will work only asp.net core 1.1,if you want to move from core 1.0 to core 1.1,look into https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

that's resolved it for me

```
"tools": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You might miss CliToolReference

```
<ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

[check this](https://www.ryadel.com/en/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef-error-in-visual-studio-2017-and-net-core-2-vs2017-entity-framework/)