# No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef" (Csproj)

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I started a project on a Mac using VS Code and ASP.NET Core MVC, here is my csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.3.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I always get "No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef""

I tried it on Windows 10 and I get the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. Please don't force tags into the title 2. Don't use ASP.NET Core and .NET Core interchangeably. They stand for completely different things

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#37276882](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765523/1233379): in short words, you need to manually edit your project configuration file and add a reference to the Tools / Tools.DotNet packages (as VS2015/VS2017 won't do that automatically). For further info, [read here](http://www.ryadel.com/en/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef-error-in-visual-studio-2017-and-net-core-2-vs2017-entity-framework/).

Comment: Also make sure you're current path is the root folder of the project. If you create a folder for a project this may be a level deeper than you expected.

Answer (score 11):

Added this to make it work:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version = "1.0.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

1. From inside the folder containing the csproj file, Add the following to the csproj file:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
       <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
       <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
2. Now include the needed dependencies by executing the following commands:

   `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
    dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
    dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
    dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet`
3. Restore the project so that all dependencies are checked upon

   `dotnet restore`
4. In order to make sure it all went ok, run the following command

   `dotnet ef`

   A screen with the basic `dotnet ef` command usage should appear
5. Check if the project is still building:

   `dotnet build`
6. Generate the scaffold from your database with the following command:

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=<your_server_address[,port_number]>;Initial Catalog=<your_db>;User Id=<your_user>;Password=<your_password>"  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -f -c YourDbContext -o Db --json`

The command above can be described as the one responsible for reading out your database and generating your scaffold poco entity classes and the dbcontext file. It requires a basic working connection string, the parameter `f` forces the overwrite, the `c` gives the context a name, the `o` determines the output folder and the namespace for the created classes and the `json` parameter outputs the command result in json instead of a zero stout.

> it is nice to keep this command at hand, it will be used anytime changes from the database must be reflected upon the ORM