# "No executable found matching command dotnet-ef" error with EF Core database-first

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, dbcontext, database-first

As you know, the newest version of Visual Studio 2017 abandons the 'project.json' and uses `.csproj` instead.

I'm using the RTM version and want to generate model from an exist database, following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db).  I got an error on the last step:

> The Entity Framework Core commands for the Package Manager Console don't yet support csproj-based .NET Core projects. Use the .NET Command Line Tools (i.e. dotnet ef) instead. For more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=834381.

Following the error, I used the link it mentioned to switch to `dotnet ef`.  Here is my package manager command:

> PM> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.;Database=Jumpstart;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Then the error comes again:

> dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

I used the help command, I found that dotnet does not have a command called ef.

I just want to generate a model from an existing database.

Comment: Could you please focus on the main subject of your question - evetually rephrase it and put it first?

Comment: You can use my VS extension, and avoid polluting your code with the scaffolding tooling: https://twitter.com/ErikEJ/status/834452863380250624

Comment: Presuming you followed the instructions on adding the <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" /> reference in your csproj, you might try just opening a command prompt and changing to the directory with your .csproj and running the command there. I could not get it to work with the VS PS prompt but cmd.exe was good to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#37276882](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765523/1233379): in short words, you need to manually edit your project configuration file and add a reference to the Tools / Tools.DotNet packages (as VS2015/VS2017 won't do that automatically). For further info, [read here](http://www.ryadel.com/en/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef-error-in-visual-studio-2017-and-net-core-2-vs2017-entity-framework/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276882/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Follow this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations

I had the same problem. Just edited the ItemGroup section in **.csproj** like this

```
<ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work when we add this package by Nuget ?!

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer is the most probable cause of the error message. However, besides adding the proper reference within `.csproj` file also **make sure that the current directory from `Package Manager Console` points to ASP.NET Core project**, otherwise any `dotnet ef` command will fail with the error mentioned in the OP title.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was solved by changing `tools` to:

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },
```

Then execute these 2 commands:

1. `dotnet restore` - to restore packages
2. dotnet ef migrations

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem

in all answer mentioned adding Tools DotNet but not solved my problem because missed some command I mention below

The EF Core .NET Command Line Tools are installed by manually editing the *.csproj file.

Add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet as a DotNetCliToolReference. See sample project below.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

for core version 2 changed the version
but after that should run 2 commands too

then importatn part in all answer missing (this command solved my problem in visuall studio 2017)

1 - Execute `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

2 - Execute `dotnet restore`. If restore does not succeed, the tools may not have installed correctly.

more information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

On NetCore 2.0 you just need to run `Add-Migrations`.

It will ask for a name and that's all. Just be sure you have a default connection string on appsettings.json