# dotnet ef database update - No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

There are many people that have asked this question before on SO. For the last 3 hours I have sequentially tried each solution, and I get the same `No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"` each time. I'd like to understand how to run the command and have it actually execute.

But first a little background:

I am learning how to use ASP.Net Core 1.1 MVC and Entity Framework Core. It is a Microsoft tutorial [that can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro).

The completed tutorial can be downloaded from git, as instructed. Performing these steps I open the download project and follow the steps in the `readme.md` file in the project root folder. It states the following:

> After downloading the project, create the database by entering `dotnet
>   ef database update` at a command-line prompt

Which I attempted. I used visual studio developer command prompt (as admin) and first change directory to the project root, where the appsettings.json and *.csproj file are located. I then typed in the following:

> C:\Users\username\Downloads\Docs-master\aspnetcore\data\ef-mvc\intro\samples\cu-final>dotnet ef database update
>
> No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

According to the tutorial, this should "work" as-is.

What is strange to me is that if I run the following command I get output, which indicates to me that dotnet.exe is working.

> C:\Users\username\Downloads\Docs-master\aspnetcore\data\ef-mvc\intro\samples\cu-final>dotnet
>   --version
>
> 1.0.4

I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 CE Version 15.2. I have both the ASP.NET and web development and .Net Core cross-platform development workloads installed.

I am also using .Net Framework Version 4.6.01586.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#37276882](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765523/1233379): in short words, you need to manually edit your project configuration file and add a reference to the Tools / Tools.DotNet packages (as VS2015/VS2017 won't do that automatically). For further info, [read here](http://www.ryadel.com/en/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef-error-in-visual-studio-2017-and-net-core-2-vs2017-entity-framework/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you restore first so that the ef tools become available:

Execute `dotnet restore` and wait for it to restore successfully, then execute `dotnet ef database update`.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` needs to be added to your project. Right click the project and select `Edit *.csproj`. Then, add the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Note: the version is the latest at the time of this post and will likely change in the future.

These tools can only be added by editing the `.proj` directly at this time.

The easiest way it run commands is to right click the project and `Open Folder in File Explorer`. Then, type `cmd` in the address bar of the `File Explorer` to open a command prompt in that folder. Now use the following command to create the initial migration:

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

Comment: Is there a way to determine which Version that I should be using? When I run the migration command I see the following: "C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CUPrimer\CUPrimer>dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
Version for package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` could not be resolved."

Comment: @sapbucket I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Preview with .Net Core 2.0 preview. The version should match the version of .Net core you are using.