# Unable to install package using dotnet

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to add the nuget package dotnet (Microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet). However,  it is not installing.

This is what I am receiving in my command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>dotnet ef --help
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

Comment: Running `dotnet ef` won't install anything, this question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i cannot install the package through my csproj or nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

The tooling for Entity Framework Core is part of the .Net Core SDK. This provides you access to `dotnet ef ...` commands. You can install the latest .Net Core SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download). More information on installing and getting started with EF Core can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/install/). The EF Core base library is also part of the meta package of ASP.Net Core (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`).

Answer (score -1):

This seems something with package.json so you should follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276882/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef)

Comment: i am getting this error below when i try to install it:      
                                                                                                         "Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools.dotnet 1.0.1 has a package type dotnetclitool that is not supported by project "The World"

I am using visual studio 2017 so i have a csproj file