# ASP.NET Core 2 migration error. No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

When I want to add a migration to my project I got the following error:

> dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

For resolving this I add the following package but I still get the same error.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design(2.0.0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet(2.0.0)
```

I found some solution but these are based on `.net-core-1` and in `.net-core-2` we don't have `project.json` file.

**update:**

Here is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Share your csproj file

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Just make sure to run dotnet restore and invoke `dotnet ef` in the directory where above csproj file is present

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276882/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef)

Answer (score 12):

In order to get `dotnet ef` to work, you need to add a `DotNetCliToolReference` element to the `.csproj`, as follows:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
```

This needs to live inside an `ItemGroup`, something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You'll also need to make sure you run `dotnet ef` from the same location as the `.csproj` file.

Comment: I have two `.csproj` file in `obj` folder, `CoreSample.Model.csproj.nuget.g.props` and `CoreSample.Model.csproj.nuget.g.targets`. I add `<ItemGroup>..</ItemGroup>` in both of them but I still got same error.

Comment: You can just right-click on the project and select `Edit XXX.csproj`, which will allow you to make the changes within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Answer]

[Link to thread](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8996)

Above worked for me after many hrs trying many other thread answers. Simply cd'ing to folder containing csproj file in package console manager was all it took. dotnet ef commands all work fine then.

Comment: Thanks MS for the frustratingly UNHELPFUL error messages - unacceptable for something like wrong folder.....sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

I know some of you will come to this question for the [*No executable found matching command “dotnet-”*] part of the title. In my case it was:

```
No executable found matching command “dotnet-My”
```

And.... it turns out my app name was "My App". Make sure your assembly name has no spaces in it. I changed it to "MyApp" and it loaded correctly.