# Enabling Migrations in EF core?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

I'm getting started with EF Core 2.0, 
I have a console application targetting .NET 4.6.1
I have a very simple model class, and this context:

```
public class ContextCore : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["efCoreCon"].ConnectionString);
    }
    public DbSet<ModelC> Models { get; set; }
}
```

this is the connection string:

```
<add name="efCoreCon" connectionString="server=PC-MSHWF\SQLEXPRESS;database=efCoreDB;integrated security=true;" />
```

I noticed that there's no command for `Enable-Migrations` in ef core from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/new-db)

so I run `Add-migration firstMigration`
but I got this error:

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly
>   'NewConsole'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations
>   command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations
>   configuration).

when I tried Enable-Migrations , I got this error:

> No context type was found in the assembly 'NewConsole'.

Comment: You're using EF non-Core commands.  Use `dotnet ef ...`.

Comment: What is the namespace of your context?

Comment: Simple tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas NewConsole.EFCore

Comment: I used `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` , but got:
dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"...

Comment: Here's how to install the EF Core tools: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to the Package Manager Console and install the needed tools with `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`. When it has completed try to use the command `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration firstMigration`.

Comment: For me just installing the package and restarting Visual Studio was enough to solve the issue

Answer (score 6):

in powershell CLI type this -->   `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration`

This enables the migration.[image]

---

This will install the [correct core tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/)

```
// Package Manger
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.0.1
// or this will work inside the CLI Console
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version 2.0.1
// **for the current/LATEST ver. leave out version option it will install latest Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

[image]

---

**Fixing your bug issue:**

Look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280326/6085193): "You should just need to update the tools section of your project.json file to include this:"

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "2.0.1",  // I corrected this from previous answer for your version
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

---

Bonus :) To **run migrations automatically**... in startup.cs of your main application.

```
// setup the HTTP request pipeline to check and migrate.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{           
    try
    {
        using (var migrationSvcScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
            .CreateScope())
        {
         migrationSvcScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<EFMigrationsMyDBContext>().Database.Migrate();
            // you can also add the data here... let me know if you need I will post it
        }
    }   
    ... // Rest of the startup stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting .NET Core 2 using C# 7.1, you can have an asynchronous `Main` method to your app,  so you can call all initialization logic before you run the host, right after it has finished building:

```cs
public class Program
{
  public static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
    //first build
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    //initialize
    using (var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
      var serviceProvider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
      var isDevelopment = 
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>().IsDevelopment();

      using var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();


      if (isDevelopment)
        await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
      else
        await context.Database.MigrateAsync();

      if (isDevelopment)
      {
        using var userManager = 
          serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
        await userManager
          .CreateAsync(new AppUser { UserName = "dummy", Email = "dummy@dumail.com" },
          password: "1234");
      }
    }

    //now run
    host.Run();
  }

  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
      {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your .csproj where you have EF Core 2.0 and add:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

1. Open Windows PowerShell
2. Go to directory where you have EF Core 2.0
3. Type `dotnet ef migrations add <<migration's_name>>`. For instance: `dotnet ef migrations add Init`. If your startup project is in different folder then you can use `--startup-project ../<<other_project_folder>>`