# Unable to enable Entity Framework migrations in .NET 4.8 ASP.NET Webforms project

Tags: c#, webforms, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I'm currently working on a home assignment where I am tasked with creating a cargo tracking application using ASP.NET Webforms and the .NET Framework 4.8. For database management, I've opted for the code-first approach and have successfully added the Entity Framework v6.4.4 package to my project.

However, when I try to enable migrations through the Package Manager Console, I get the following error:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

> Enable-Migrations : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Enable-Migrations
> - 
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Enable-Migrations], RuntimeException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Enable-Migrations

Here are the steps I've taken in an attempt to solve this problem:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled the Entity Framework package
- Created a new project from scratch
- Ran Visual Studio as an Administrator
- Tried to enable migrations for the specific `DbContext`:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName App.DAL.CargoContext
```

Unfortunately, none of the above have been successful in resolving the issue.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and my project is structured as follows:

```
- App_Start
- Content
- DAL
    - CargoContext.cs
- Models
    - Cargo.cs
    - Customer.cs
- Scripts
- Web.config
```

`CargoContext.cs`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using App.Models;

namespace App.DAL
{
    public class CargoContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Cargo> Cargos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help or insight into what could be causing this problem and how to fix it. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47599788/11483367) will help solve your question.

Comment: I am using EntityFramework, not EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: You will likely have an easier time finding resources if you used up to date versions. EF Core 3.x works fine with .Net framework 4.8, but you should ideally use the latest version of .NET & EF unless you have some specific requirements. If the goal is to learn I see little point of using outdated libraries.