# Entity Framework Core 2.0 add-migration not generating anything

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I'm new to EF and am trying to create a simple test solution using VS 2017, .NET Core 2.0 and EF 2.0 but I can't get *add-migration* to create the migrations folder and the initial migration.

I have created a solution called *Driver* with two .Net Core class library projects:

```
Driver.Data
Driver.Domain
```

The following packages are installed in *Driver.Data*:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

*Driver.Data* has a single cs file called *Driver.Context*:

```
using Driver.Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Driver.Data
{
    public class DriverContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database=Driver; Trusted_Connection=True;"
                );
        }
    }

}
```

*Driver.Domain* has a single cs file called *Company.cs*:

```
namespace Driver.Domain
{
    public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've set the startup project to *Driver.Data* and in the PM Console I've set the Default Project to *Driver.Data*

Here is the output of *add-migration init -verbose*:

```
Using project 'Driver.Data'.
Using startup project 'Driver.Data'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile "C:\Users\alex.florin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Driver\trunk\Driver.Data\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Driver.Data.deps.json" --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\alex.florin\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --fx-version 2.0 "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.0.1\tools\netcoreapp2.0\ef.dll" migrations add init --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly "C:\Users\alex.florin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Driver\trunk\Driver.Data\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Driver.Data.dll" --startup-assembly "C:\Users\alex.florin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Driver\trunk\Driver.Data\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Driver.Data.dll" --project-dir "C:\Users\alex.florin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Driver\trunk\Driver.Data\\" --root-namespace Driver.Data
```

There are no errors but nothing is being generated.

Comment: Well, if I recreate the projects using the Class Library (.NET Framework) project template, add-migration works. It doesn't work if the projects are Class Library (.NET Core). Why?

Comment: 2 tips.  1. Make sure the startup Project is set to be the one in which migrations should occur on. 2. Make sure that your Program.cs contains the Function `BuildWebHost` because .Net Core 2. uses duck typing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@JulieLerman provided the answer when I asked in her pluralsight course discussion. There is apparently an issue with attempting this with the .NET Core class libraries. The successful workaround is to put the following in the csproj file of the DBContext project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConf‌igurationFiles> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

She wrote a blog about it:
http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/the-secret-to-running-ef-core-2-0-migrations-from-a-net-core-or-net-standard-class-library/

Additionally, be sure to set the project with the DBContext in it as the startup project

Comment: Might be worth also adding to this (as it says in @JulieLerman 's blog) you also have to set the project with the DBContext in it as the startup project (this got me at first).

Comment: some times clearing the data from "temp" directory would solve some of the issues,  C:\Users\<logonuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\

Answer (score 1):

I had issues when I attempt to get it to work as well as far as I am concerned EF Core 2.0 is not fully ready for prime time as the main dotnet core commands don't work out of the box.  In addition to what you did I had to run a few more things to get it to work in the project file itself.  I followed these two threads:
https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/645
and Joe Healy's answer here:
[No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276882/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef)

In essence it would do nothing or give a very basic error.  It ended up being that the hook up of the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet were not working correctly and needed to be set in the 'ItemGroup' in my .NET Core 2 project like so:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I also believe you need to use a slightly different code for making the migrations work utilizing dotnet that calls out commands for 'dotnet core'.  Followed by 'ef'.  So I just did this on my test solution:

```
dotnet ef migrations add test
```

and it worked.  You must, must, be in the same folder level as your project when doing the commands for migrations or database updates.  If you are still having trouble feel free to take a look at a project I created on GitHub:

https://github.com/djangojazz/EFCoreTest/tree/master/EFCoreCodeFirstScaffolding

Comment: Thanks. I'm using .Tools (for the PMC) not .Tools.DotNet (for the command line). I'm getting some advice from another source to put the following in the csproj file but that hasn't helped: 

    <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>

Comment: I cannot recall as I did this all two months or so ago but I think some of the places I went were dead ends so I ended up using the dotnet ef commands as the others 'Tools' would not work.  Let me know if you get further though as obviously .NET Core 2 is bleeding edge still and they are making changes fast and furious to VS 2017 and .NET Core 2.