# Error running update-database entityframeworkcore 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have `EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.2` installed in a class library on a solution containing an AspNet Core WebApi.

I have the following packages installed in the project;

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore - 2.0.2
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore - 2.0.2
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer - 2.0.2
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores - 2.0.2
>
> System.Data.SqlClient - 4.4.3

My Class library project invokes the context as follows;

```
 public class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDataContext>
    {
        public MyContextFactory()
        {
        }

        public MyDataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDataContext>();
            builder.UseSqlServer(DbGlobals.DevDatabase);

            return new MyDataContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error, when I try to run the `update-database` command from the package manager console.

> Application startup exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not find file
>   'C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\project\Services.WebApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\ef.xml'.

this now occurs when I try to `add-migration` as well.

I can't find any detail on ef.xml and how it is generated? Can anyone tell me what is going on here.

If I run an `add-migration` i get the migration generated, but then get the error;

> An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Could not find file `'C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\project\Services.WebApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\ef.xml'.`

I have tried cleaning the project, re-compiling (there are no errors), I have also looked in the referenced folder and the file doesn't exist. Nor (from a file search) has it been generated elsewhere?

The migrations have been working fine now?

Per request my `BuildwebHost` is;

```
 public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

and I add EF in my Startup.cs;

```
        services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(
            options => options
            .UseSqlServer(DbGlobals.DevDatabase));
```

Comment: Is this a .net core application? Do you have any DB initializer class that needs invoking in Main?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I will update the question. EF is actually installed to a class library with a Asp.Net Core Webapi 2.

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are using `update-database` and `add-migration` don´t look like the supported Entity Framework Core CLI commands:

- `dotnet ef add migrations <migration-name>`
- `dotnet ef database update`

Also check this SO question for further information:
[Entity Framework Core 2.0 add-migration not generating anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102431/entity-framework-core-2-0-add-migration-not-generating-anything)

Comment: there powershell extensions should work though I believe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell I have neevr installed the tools package before on any other core project (I suppose its worth a go).

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error, but it actually worked flawlessly with the `Package Manager Console` and `Core CLI`. Can you add the code from your `BuildWebHost` method and the `Startup`?

Comment: yes no problem. did you use the `update-database` command or `dotnet ef database update`? out of interest? its odd as it was working and something has changed to cause this. any ideas what ef.xml actually contains? does you project generate this? or is this part of the package? as I have updated these all.

Comment: I tried both commands. Both were working. And my project did not generate a ef.xml. Or I just did not see it (although I searched for it)

Comment: Thats great, you helped me track down the issue. I had enabled Swagger UI for my Webapi GUI. I had enabled Xml comments on it which tries to load in a .xml file from the debug folder. Now because technically it was the class library running (althought through the webapi), hence it was looking for the Ef.xml (my class library is services.ef).

Comment: Long story short I disabled the code `                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);` in my swagger generation and the update-database worked fine

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: wouldnt have seen that if you hadn't pointed it out. happy for you to answer with that if you want and I'll accept.

Comment: Just go ahead and answer yourself. You did basically all the hard work.