# Asp.Net Core 2.1 add-migration is not picking up properties in class that inherits from IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I am working on an ASP.Net Core 2.1.1 web application in VS2017 v15.8.2, using the web application template with individual user accounts.

I want to add more properties to the IdentityUser so I created an `ApplicationUser` class that inherits from `IdentityUser`. I applied the appropriate updates to the startup.cs and _loginPartial.cshtml. Everything compiles, but when I run `Add-Migration` it doesn't pick up the properties in my `ApplicationUser` class.  I have a migration class but the up and down methods have no properties.

I only have one project so selecting the Default Project is not the issue in Package Manager Console.

Here is my ApplicationUser class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my DBContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the service in Startup.cs, ConfigureService

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.
        GetConnectionString("AccountDbConnectionString")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Here is the add-migration in Package Manager Console

```
Add-Migration -c ApplicationDbContext V1.00.01
```

Here is the resultant migration

```
public partial class V10001 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

The `ApplicationUser` class is in the Models folder off the project root.

The `IdentityUser` was parsed for the initial Asp.Net Core Web Application template migration when I first created the project and when I ran the update-database command, it created all of the AspNetUserxxx and AspNetRolexxx tables in the database just fine.

But I cannot see why EF Migrations is not seeing the `ApplicationUser` class so it can add the new properties to the migration class.

When I look for examples online, it looks like I am doing everything correctly to extend the `IdentyUser` properties.

What am I missing?

EDIT 1: I tried the solution in this SO post but it made no difference.
[Entity Framework Core 2.0 add-migration not generating anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102431/entity-framework-core-2-0-add-migration-not-generating-anything)

Answer (score 4):

change your `ApplicationDbContext` as below :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

}
```

here's screenshot that works:

[image]

**[Update ]:** I just find that the answer by @vivek nuna works too .You can choose as you like .

**[Update]** : If you run into an exception like :

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
```

InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

don't forget to update the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` in which the `SignInManager` and `UserManager` reference the `IdentityUser` , i.e. , change the code from :

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

to

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `ApplicationUser` class in DBContext.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then Add migration and then Update database.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm using the ASP.NET Core identity package, all pages related to login and authentication, like _LoginPartial, must be changed from:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

To:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

It's also important that the ApplicatiuonDbContext be changed:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
```

And the database migration must be then, done.