# No executable found matching command “dotnet-ef”

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, dotnet-cli

When I run `dotnet ef` I got the following error message

> No executable found matching command “dotnet-ef”

I have no idea how to solve this issue,i tried every possible solution.

this how my .csproj looks like

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="ClientApp\**" />
    <Content Remove="ClientApp\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="ClientApp\**" />
    <None Remove="ClientApp\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You will find the solution to your problem here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276882/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276882/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef)

Comment: @René Thanks Bro, it works for me